# Get statuscode text in C#

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm using a plugin and want to perform an action based on the records statuscode value. I've seen online that you can use `entity.FormattedValues["statuscode"]` to get values from option sets but when try it I get an error saying "The given key was not present in the dictionary".

I know this can happen when the plugin cant find the change for the field you're looking for, but i've already checked that this does exist using `entity.Contains("statuscode")` and it passes by that fine but still hits this error.

Can anyone help me figure out why its failing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not seen the `entity.FormattedValues` before.

I usually use the `entity.Attributes`, e.g. `entity.Attributes["statuscode"]`.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.entity.attributes)

---

**Edit**

Crm wraps many of the values in objects which hold additional information, in this case statuscode uses the OptionSetValue, so to get the value you need to:

```
((OptionSetValue)entity.Attributes["statuscode"]).Value
```

This will return a number, as this is the underlying value in Crm.

If you open up the customisation options in Crm, you will usually (some system fields are locked down) be able to see the label and value for each option.

[image]

If you need the label, you could either do some hardcoding based on the information in Crm.

Or you could retrieve it from the metadata services as described [here](http://andreaswijayablog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/crm-2011-get-optionsetvalue-label-text.html).

Comment: I've seen FormattedValues before used to get option set values, but not really used it much myself. When i try to use entity.Attributes["statuscode"] it just returns "Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue"

Comment: @JamesWood I believe OP is after the text that accompanies the Status Code rather than underlying integer. I've only used this property before with currency fields though. SDK has scant information but I suspect it is only valid for number and currency attributes.

Comment: I was originally after the text label of the statuscode, however i can work with the value. Thank you both for your help

Answer (score 3):

To avoid your error, you need to check the collection you wish to use (rather than the `Attributes` collection):

```
if (entity.FormattedValues.Contains("statuscode")){
    var myStatusCode = entity.FormattedValues["statuscode"];
}
```

However although the SDK fails to confirm this, I suspect that `FormattedValues` are only ever present for numeric or currency attributes. (Part-speculation on my part though).

Comment: It would appear that that is the case, I have just tried your code and while the error is gone it doesn't pick up the value. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

entity.FormattedValues work only for string display value.

For example you have an optionset with display names as 1, 2, 3,
The  above statement do not recognize these values because those are integers. If You have seen the exact defintion of formatted values in the below link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.formattedvaluecollection.aspx

you will find this statement is valid for only string display values. If you try to use this statement with Integer values it will throw key not found in dictionary exception.

So try to avoid this statement for retrieving integer display name optionset in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string Title = (bool)entity.Attributes.Contains("title") ? entity.FormattedValues["title"].ToString() : "";
```

When you are talking about Option set, you have value and label. What this will give you is the label. '?' will make sure that the null value is never passed.